# Flutter Document Xd Margin

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart:267:15 margin == null || margin.isNonNegative is not true See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart:267:15 margin == null || margin.isNonNegative is not true See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Comment: Impossible to debug without seeing your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

the `margin` can't accept negative values, this seems what you did.
using this is wrong :

```
EdgeInsets.all(-5),
```